# Twitter bootstrap tooltip, get the creator object

Tags: jquery, tooltip, d3.js

Is there a way to link the creator object of the tooltip to the tooltip itself.

The issue is that when the tooltip is created, it parent is always body so the link between the creating element and the tooltip itself is lost.

-- Edit:

When you create a tooltip, what twitter-bootstrap does is create a new DOM element for that tooltip. However, instead of placing it relative to the element that created it, it put its under the body element.

For example, if you have a `<a>` link on your HTML that creates a tooltip, the tooltip element itself is placed under the body element, losing completely the relation to the `<a>` element that created it.

Now imagine that I have two tooltips at the same time. There is no way of telling which is which in the code.

Comment: explain in detail what issue is... your code and a demo would help. "link lost" is not very clear

Comment: How are you creating your tooltip? If you are using a d3.append then you should be able to simultaneously set attributes to maintain whatever relationship you want.